# Detect end of Windows display resolution change

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-10

I am trying to develop a background utility for **Windows** with the following features :

1. store position of open application windows for the current display resolution **Rx**
2. scan for any change in display resolution **Rx** -> **Ry** (e.g. related to docking/undocking my laptop to/from its docking station)
3. wait for Windows to finish automatic repositioning of the windows (*messy desktop reconfiguration*; see below)
4. restore the previously stored windows position for the display resolution **Ry**

I have successfully implemented features 1, 2 and 4. For feature 2, I intercept the `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` event, telling me that a change in display resolution has occurred.

Immediately after the resolution change occurs, **Windows** automatically repositions many (if not all) windows to meet the new display constraints. This phase (which I call the *messy desktop reconfiguration*) lasts several seconds and causes a real mess in the windows layout (which is why I want to develop the said utility).

Now I have the following problem:

I can only apply feature 4 when Windows has finished the *messy desktop reconfiguration* phase (3). However, I have not found any acceptable way to detect when this phase ends.

I did try to observe the automatic repositioning of windows by intercepting the `EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE` event, and then wait for the last one to be issued. It almost works: I am well notified when it happens, however, I'm not satisfied because the time interval between each of these events can last up to 5 seconds (or maybe more), which makes it difficult to identify the last of these events by a classic timeout method. Currently, I have set this timeout to 10 seconds, which is not satisfactory because I would like to be able to detect the end of the *messy desktop reconfiguration* earlier and, more importantly, there is no guarantee that another of these events will not occur after the timeout.

**Does anyone have a solution to properly detect the end of automatic windows repositonning, when changing the display resolution ?**